# Unable to build and push Docker image into (private) Artifactory from GitLab CI using kaniko

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, artifactory, kaniko

I'm designing a GitLab CI pipeline to build a Docker image for a given service.

This is how (the relevant excerpt from) the Gitlab CI manifest looks like so far:

```yaml
...

publish-docker-image:
  stage: publish
  dependencies:
    - assemble
  image:
    name: docker.tld.com/namespace/kaniko:latest # At work they offer a custom kaniko image
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir --parents /kaniko/.docker/
    - mv $kaniko_config /kaniko/.docker/config.json # $kaniko_config is a file variable from GitLab CI
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination artifactory.tld.com/artifactory/docker-snapshot/organization/project/kaniko-test:0.1.0
```

The `$kaniko_config` file translates into this JSON:

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://artifactory.tld.com/": {
      "username": "the_real_username",
      "password": "the_real_password"
    }
  }
}
```

Now every time I run the pipeline I get this output:

```sh
$ mkdir --parents /kaniko/.docker/
$ mv $kaniko_config /kaniko/.docker/config.json
$ cat /kaniko/.docker/config.json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://artifactory.tld.com/": {
      "username": "the_real_username",
      "password": "the_real_password"
    }
  }
}
$ /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination artifactory.tld.com/artifactory/docker-snapshot/organization/project/kaniko-test:0.1.0
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "artifactory.tld.com/artifactory/docker-snapshot/organization/project/kaniko-test:0.1.0": creating push check transport for artifactory.tld.com failed: GET https://artifactory.tld.com/v2/: : Not Found
Cleaning up file based variables
```

What am I doing wrong here? Moreover, I don't know why the error message have `https://artifactory.tld.com/v2/` (the `/v2`) on it since I'm not using anything like that.

Comment: It looks like you Docker registry is wrong.
The `https://artifactory.tld.com/` should be replaced by the configured Artifactory Docker registry. 
It depends on your reverse proxy configuration and it should be the same as using for a `docker login <docker-registry>` command. 
You can view the docker registry by using the "Set Me Up" button:
 https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-SetMeUp

Comment: @yahavi, you were correct, the Docker registry URL was wrong. Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer to anyone who encounters this issue in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone who encounters this issue in the future -
the `kaniko-config.json` file should have the following structure:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "<artifactory-docker-registry>": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The "artifactory-docker-registry" can be retrieved using the [Set Me Up](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-SetMeUp) button in the JFrog platform UI.